# \cite command doesn't work with bibunits Package

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, bibunits

I'm using the **bibunits** package to produce multiple bibliographies for a book. I'm using the first method with `\bibliographyunit[\chapter]`  with two different databases **base1** and **base2** here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
    \bibliographyunit[\chapter]
    \defaultbibliographystyle{plain}

    \chapter{The First Chapter}
    Refer to \cite{Knuth-CT}, and \cite{Knuth-TB} for more info.
    \putbib[base1] 
    
    \defaultbibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \chapter{The Second Chapter}
    Refer to \cite{MR-PQ}, and \cite{3DLM} for more info.
    \putbib[base2]
    
\end{document}
```

**The bibliographies are generated without problems in both chapters**

---

[image]

---

**but the citations in the text are not resolved**

---

[image]

---

and I'm getting the error ***Citation XXX on page XXX undefined on input line XXX***, knowing that the keys in the `\cite` commands match exactly those in the `.bib` files, and the compiling sequence is correct for all auxiliary files.

Here are the `.bib` files:

**base1.bib**

```
@Book{Knuth-CT,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "The {\TeX}book",
    publisher = "Ad{\-d}i{\-s}on-Wes{\-l}ey",
    address = "Reading, MA, USA",
    volume = "A",
    series = "Computers and Typesetting",
    pages = "ix + 483",
    year = 1986,
    isbn = "0-201-13447-0"
}

@Article{Knuth-TB,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "{Typesetting Concrete Mathematics}",
    journal = "TUGboat",
    volume = "10",
    number = "1",
    pages = "31--36",
    year = 1989,
    month = apr,
    issn = "0896-3207"
}
```

**base2.bib**

```
@InProceedings{MR-PQ,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The Pursuit of Quality: How can Automated Typesetting achieve the Highest Standards of Craft Typography?",
    pages = "261--273"
}

@misc{3DLM,
      title={3D Line Mapping Revisited}, 
      author={Shaohui Liu and Yifan Yu and Rémi Pautrat and Marc Pollefeys and Viktor Larsson},
      year={2023},
      eprint={2303.17504},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={cs.CV}
}
```

I keek getting this **LaTeX Warning: Citation `Knuth-CT' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.** for all citation entries.

I hope that you have a clue about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you re-run latex enough times to resolve the citations? If so and it doesn't work, please edit the question to provide an example that shows the problem.

Comment: I did run it multiple times and nothing changed, I will add the .bib files to make things more clear.

Comment: are the bbl generated? they are not for me (as I haven't the input) and I get in the log `No file bu2.bbl` do you see the same, or are the `.bbl` generated but empty?

Comment: The input is the MWE in the question (that's what I'm running), and the `.bll` files are generated for both with the correct bibitems. I ran `pdflatex` so many times after `bibtex` and still the error is there.

Comment: `\bibcite{3DLM}{1}
\bibcite{MR-PQ}{2}
` are written to the log file not an aux file, which means the aux got closed prematurely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work as I expect,
however the `bibunit` environment does produce the expected output.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}[plain]
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
    Refer to \cite{Knuth-CT}, and \cite{Knuth-TB} for more info.
    \putbib[base1] 
\end{bibunit}


\begin{bibunit}[abbrv]
    \chapter{The Second Chapter}
    Refer to \cite{MR-PQ}, and \cite{3DLM} for more info.
    \putbib[base2]
\end{bibunit}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actaully have found a solution from the package documentation. It says in  `Section 3.2` that when using the method of `\bibliographyunit[<unit>]` it's advisable to have the package option `sectionbib` for chapter bibliography, and `subsectionbib` for section level, quoting "for the proper behavior of the bibunits package." So, `\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}` for me solved this case. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AmmarTaha if you want to post that as an answer that might help others who get here.

Comment: Sure, I will add it now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to add a package option, either sectionbib (for chapter level bib) or subsectionbib (for section level bib), in the documentation of the package, `3.2 Bibunits by chapters or sections` it says that when using the method of `\bibliographyunit[<unit>]` it is essential to have one of these options for the proper behavior of the package. So, for this question, using `\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}` resolved the citation problem for me.